# web service communication over nRF24L01

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi

I have two peaces of nRFO24L01, one of them is connected to arduino and second one is connected to RPi. For communication between them I used this library https://github.com/tmrh20/RF24 and this communication working very good. Now I want to have web services on RPi which have to be able to communicate with arduino through the nRF24L01. The best option should be some java web services on tomcat server but I can't manage to find some kind of wrapper which will provide me easily connection between c++ code from mentioned library and web services. Is there any solution for this?

For communication between arduino and RPi I used getting started example from mentioned library from github.

Answer (score -1):

See the RF24Ethernet lib from the same guy:

http://tmrh20.github.io/RF24Ethernet/